# Fixing non-breaking text in jspx page

Tags: html, web-applications, textarea, jspx

I have a webapp with one particular .jspx page where I'm having a problem with an empty text box in a table. In this snippet of code (edited here for size because the page is way long):

```
<table cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="color: #ff6699;">
Please add descriptive keywords
<br>
and any comments *
</td>
<!-- the line below is the problem-->
<td>
<input id="{c08485a6-60c0-554e-90a1-96d3cf7c6ff7}" style="width:150px; height: 50px; font-size: 11px; border: 1px solid;" name="Asset Description">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
<input style="visibility: hidden; height: 5px;">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="border-top: 1px dotted #ff6699; padding-top: 10px;" colspan="2">
<span style="font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; color: #ff6699;">Tell us about yourself.</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
</tr>
<tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

...if I type in the description field, the text does not wrap and simply scrolls the text endlessly to the right on one line as you type:

**(Since I can't post images... imagine this is how my text would type in the box endlessly on one line to the right without wrapping)**

I've tried changing 'input id=...' to 'textarea id=...', and when I test in html the text box functions EXACTLY the way I want it to:

**(Again, since no images...

imagine this is how my text

should wrap within my

text box.)**

However, if I load the .jspx page with the new code and test in my app, when I click on this particular function, it blows up my entire web app and I'm back to the login page with an 'end of session' message.

Pouring over this (and other boards) I'm reading that 'textarea...' needs special handling when used in a .jspx page, but I'm not finding the correct syntax I need. I've tried using a closing tag (/textarea>) but the page/function is still broken.

Any ideas how I might get me a nice, clean, wrapping text box? Many thanks to all!!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible, you'd have to use a `<textarea></textarea>` to allow for multiple lines.

Comment: I've tried this:
`<td>
<textarea id="{c08485a6-60c0-554e-90a1-96d3cf7c6ff7}" style="width:150px; height: 50px; font-size: 11px; border: 1px solid;" name="Asset Description"></textarea>
</td>`
and this:
`<td>
<textarea id="{c08485a6-60c0-554e-90a1-96d3cf7c6ff7}" style="width:150px; height: 50px; font-size: 11px; border: 1px solid;" name="Asset Description"><jsp:text /></textarea>
</td>`
but it still errors.

Answer (score 0):

Found it! I needed either at least one character before the "" closing tag otherwise the rest of my code was rendered as the text. I inserted &160; as a non-breaking space before the closing tag:
`<td valign="top">
    <textarea id="{c08485a6-60c0-554e-90a1-96d3cf7c6ff7}" style="width:150px; height: 50px; font-size: 11px; border: 1px solid;" name="Asset Description">&160;</textarea>
</td>`